# Nuxt 3 useNuxtApp() returns type unknown

Tags: typescript, nuxt3

I try to provide a helper to be usable across all composables and application in Nuxt plugin, and the code looks like this:

```
// hello.ts
export default defineNuxtPlugin(async nuxtApp => {

  nuxtApp.vueApp.provide('hello', (name: string) => `Hello ${name}!`);
  nuxtApp.provide('hello', (name: string) => `Hello ${name}!`)

});
```

after that, I try to call the helper by using `useNuxtApp()` in a composable as shown below, however, the type the useNuxtApp()` returns is unknown.

```
// useHello.ts
export default async function() {
    const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp()
    console.log(nuxtApp.$hello('name'))
}
```

The error I get is `nuxtApp.$hello' is of type 'unknown'.`

I have followed the [documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/nuxt-app), and I do not understand why it is returning type unknown.

Am I missing something? maybe in nuxt.config.ts?

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 7):

this error occurred after VsCode 1.79 update.
the issue is related to VsCode TypeScript version.

after 1.79 version typescript version is updated and "Volar" is using the new typesript version.
to solve the issue press `Ctrl + Shift + p` then write "Select TypeScript Version" and then choose "Use workspace version".

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I created an interface for my plugin. So I created the NuxtApp module interface with my injected plugin interface.

Some thing like this:

```js
// plugins/api.ts

interface IApi {
  baseURL: string;
  auth: AuthModule;
  ...
}

declare module "#app" {
  interface NuxtApp {
    $api: IApi;
  }
}

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  /** an object containing all repositories we need to expose */
  const modules: IApi = {
    baseURL: nuxtApp.$config.public.API_BASE_URL,
    auth: new AuthModule(),
    ...
  };

  return {
    provide: {
      api: modules,
    },
  };
})
```

Now I can import the plugin with right typed interface in anywhere on my application directly from useNuxtApp.

```js
  const { $api } = useNuxtApp();
  console.log($api.baseURL)
```

Answer (score 3):

I has same problem.
I add below to my typings file(like my.d.ts), it's resloved.

```
declare function useNuxtApp(): NuxtApp;
```

Comment: It is working but I don't understand why is there any need to declare the function.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to provide the helper (`hello`) from a `plugin`, you can return an object with the `provide` key as it is mentioned [here](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins#automatically-providing-helpers):

> If you would like to provide a helper on the NuxtApp instance, return it from the plugin under a provide key. For example:
>
> ```
> export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
>  return {
>      provide: {
>          hello: (msg: string) => `Hello ${msg}!`
>      }
>  }
> })
> ```

I would also like to mention that Nuxt 3 uses the `utils/` directory to automatically import helper functions and other utilities throughout your application using auto-imports ([Nuxt3 Utils/](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/utils)).